Are these cells likely to be in series or parallel or both
Here is a Dell product that is battery operated.  Link to a website selling a Dell computer.
The buyer can choose from 3 battery options.  From this would you infer that the different options produce a different DC voltage (because they are in series) or would you think the greater number of Watt-hours provided by the batteries with more cells is because the cells are in parallel?


The "best for..." descriptions are really just marketing-speak variations on "low capacity", "medium capacity", and "high capacity".

Could you please to post a link  to a specific Dell product which offers all these battery options in the same model line?

@Ale..chenski The Dell website seems to suggest that for the model linked, the user can choose from 3 different batteries but there is no configurator so maybe I need to phone them or setup an account.? Another anecdote: when I search Ebay for a replacement for the Lenovo IdeaPad 3 15IML05, there is a 35W 7.6 volt and a 45Wh 11.1 V battery offered. Don't trust Ebay vendors? I have an IdeaPad 3 15IML05 and the original battery is the 7.6 volt battery and currently the Lenovo website doesn't offer the 7.6 volt battery but it does offer the 11. volt battery as an exact match.

The Dell's "which battery is right for you" is a general-purpose blurb for education of dummies. The other topic in the group "What is a computer battery" proves the above point. However, I found one laptop that offers 4 and 6 cells geometries, https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-laptops/precision-5680-workstation/spd/precision-16-5680-laptop/xctop5680usvp?view=configurations , but it does not necessarily mean that the internal mainboard is the same for both batteries. Otherwise the more powerful battery would be offered as an after-sale option.

The Ideapad 3 15IML05 has 13 sub-models, some with different 35Wh and 45Wh batteries https://psref.lenovo.com/Product/IdeaPad/IdeaPad_3_15IML05 To talk about "exact match" you need to start with exact model number, which apparently you omitted.


Are these cells likely to be in series or parallel or both

The two smaller ones in series, the larger one both.

3 cell: 3S - 3 LCO cells in series (3 x 3.85 V = 11.55 V)
4 cell: 4S - 4 LFP cells in series (4 x 3.2 V = 12.8 V) (Or possibly: 4 LCO cells, 15.4 V)
6 cell: 2P3S - 6 LCO cells in series and parallel (3 x 3.85 V = 11.55 V)


I believe that by default an electronics engineer would not open a device and replace a 11.5V battery with a 15.4V battery so your information implies that doing so is okay and therefore against the default behaviour. This is kinda "big news" to me and the focus of sales literature on "Watt-hours" and "Amp-hours" elides the news about voltage.

@H2ONaCl - That's why my first supposition is that the 4-cell battery uses LFP Li-ion cells.

The Watt-Hour rating is a measure of energy. It is independent of voltage or battery wiring configuration. It tells you the capacity of the battery pack expressed as Watts times Hours. So for an 86Wh battery pack, if your computer burns a constant 86 watts, it should run for 1 hour on a full charge. If it burns a constant 43 watts for the discharge cycle, it should run for 2 hours (43W * 2h = 86WH). The Wh product is constant for any power consumption and time for a given charge. If the power consumption varies over the discharge cycle, use calculus.
I will assume the pack configuration based on some reasoning and experience. First, I'm going to assume the pack chemistry is Li-ion as most laptops are using this technology per this writing. That gives you a cell voltage of nominally 3.7V.
The 3-cell pack is "3s", or 3 cells in series for a pack voltage of 11.1V
The 4-cell pack is "4s", or 4 cells in series for a pack voltage of 14.8V
The 6-cell pack is either "6s" for 22.2V or more likely, "2p3s" which would be 3 series of 2 cells each. Which is just a "doubled up" of the "3s"
To figure out the capacity (Wh) of 1 cell in the pack, just divide the pack capacity by the number of cells.

6s is "very unlikely" since the typical industry-standard input voltage is 19V-20V. Apparently the product can accommodate both 11.1V and 14.8V batteries.

@Ale..chenski The reason I am asking is because I bought a battery for a Lenovo computer which is described as 11.1V.  The original battery is 7.6V. I hesitated to install the battery. The Lenovo website does offer "Lenovo BATTERY, 11.1V, 45 Wh, 3cell" when my search term is the laptop model number but I don't completely trust my reading of the laptop model number because the print is tiny.

@H2ONaCl don't carelessly switch batteries from different manufactures unless you really know what you're doing. It's not simply the cell count and voltages that govern compatibility. There's active electronics in the battery for charging and communication to the host. Best case: It might work. Next best case, it doesn't charge. Worst-case: your battery or laptop fails/goes on fire. Use a qualified replacement - you will get true capacity, compatibility, and safety that comes with using authorized replacements. Why risk it?

A different manufacturer is a risk of it's own. I've had no problem with "compatible" batteries in the past so I'm more concerned about voltages.

In a Q on electronics.stackexhange.com subsequently voted closed and deleted I posted my Lenovo battery question and 2 very high rep (40k+) commenters said the new battery should not be used. If laptops are commonly designed for a range of DC voltages I feel like the "news" isn't really out or I missed the memo. Maybe some people are looking at Watt-hours and happy with bigger numbers but people who "know better" are missing out if the boards accept higher DC volts but they don't know it.
